# What verb to use with the word 'breach'? 'Seal'?

Tags: word-request

If you put an end to a breach (in the sense of "unauthorized access", for example to a computer server), what verb could I use? Maybe, 'seal'? Or maybe simply 'close'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say

> We have patched the breach.

This meaning of patch is in common use in computer technology. It is a noun and also a verb, as [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/patch) shows:

> **patch**
>   TRANSITIVE VERB
>
> **4** *Computing*
>   Correct, enhance, or modify (a routine or program) by inserting a patch.

Microsoft's monthly system update schedule is called [**Patch Tuesday**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday).

Answer (score 0):

You could just say "we have put an end to the breach".

However, you could also say that you have *secured* the system.

Comment: I need 'breach' as the object. Please suggest one or more verbs

Comment: I suggested a verb.  it is in italics If you need to clarify your question, please edit it.

Comment: I would recommend _close_.

Comment: @JamesK You should've read the second AND the first sentence of my comment

Comment: @KateBunting What do you think about 'seal'?

Comment: I did read it.  The verb to use is "secure".  As in "I have secured the server". That answers the question.  If you feel you need to add clarification, then edit your question. The question does not specify that "breach" needs to be the object.  Nor have you given any reason why you **need** breach as the object.